# How to change MaterialAlertDialog text color properly?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-components-android, material-components

I try to use widgets from Material Components only, but in many cases, it's not documented how styling can be achieved.

Let's consider `MaterialAlertDialog`.

Each time I want to show a dialog, I call such part of the code:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context, R.style.Theme_MyApp_Dialog_Alert)
    .setTitle("Title")
    .setMessage("This is message.")
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok) { _, _ -> }
    .show()
```

As you can see, I'm using a custom theme.

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dialog.Alert" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <!-- attributes here -->
</style>
```

The problem is that some of the attributes are not working. For example `textColor`. So the question is how to change the body or title text color in `MaterialAlertDialog`?

I use the newest version of Material Components - `1.1.0-alpha07`.

PS.

I'm not sure which theme should be a parent. In [Material Theme Builder](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/material-theme-builder) they use `@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert` which actually gives an "old" look of dialogs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the style as below

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dialog.Alert" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MaterialAlertDialogText</item>
</style>
```

Create `MaterialAlertDialogText` style and set textColor

```
<style name="MaterialAlertDialogText" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/yourTextColor</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can simply override the default colors using:

```
  <style name="Theme.MyApp.Dialog.Alert" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">

     <!-- Text Color for title and message -->
     <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
     ....
  </style>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can customize the style used by the title and the body text using:

```
  <style name="Theme.MyApp.Dialog.Alert" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">    
      <!-- Title -->
      <item name="materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle">@style/MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text</item>

     <!-- Body -->
     <item name="materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle">@style/BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTitle_MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/....</item>
  </style>

  <style name="BodyTextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2" parent="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Body.Text">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/....</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed-light</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Material3 does not seem to have `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog`.