# Justify text content in MaterialAlertDialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

Very straight forward question.
Is possible to justify the message content in the `MaterialAlertDialog` I find really absurd that 2021 google/android fights to do simple text processing that any "microsoft word" would do in 1991

Is there any way to achieve it without create a custom TextView and insert it in the dialog manually?

Comment: I do not see anything named `MaterialAlertDialog`. Are you referring to `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` by any chance? If so, it looks like your options are based on the text appearances that you provide via `materialAlertDialogTitleTextStyle` and `materialAlertDialogBodyTextStyle` -- see https://stackoverflow.com/q/56905297/115145 for some examples.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how to set the text appearances to be justified?

Comment: I have not considered text justification in Android in years. To me, it is doomed to look bad on some combinations of text, locale, available space, and font scale. But, based on a quick search, it looks like you could try [setting `android:justificationMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView#android:justificationmode) in your dialog's theme, on Android 8.0+.

Comment: Appreciated, and in imho non justified text looks bad in any combination of size/space it resembles very much a kid writing without care